# Problem with Exclusions when Floor is used

Tags: plotting, discontinuity

```
Plot[Floor[Sin[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Floor[Sin[x]],  Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed],  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Table[x, {x, {-Pi, 0, Pi}}], None}},  ExclusionsStyle -> {Dotted, Red}, PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-1, 1}}]
```

which gives
[image]

While I expect something like this, espeacially when `x=Pi/2`, for example, should be `1`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It misses it due to sampling. You can see this by asking to explicitly sample `Pi/2`

```
Plot[Floor[Sin[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotPoints -> {50, {Pi/2}},
 PlotLabel -> Floor[Sin[x]],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed],
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Table[x, {x, {-Pi, 0, Pi}}], None}},
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dotted, Red},
 PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-1, 1.1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just adding more sample points did not help, it kept missing `Pi/2`. One way around this is to make 2 plots and use `Show`

```
f[x_] := If[Mod[x, Pi/2] != 0, Null, Sin[x]]
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/10}];
p1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red];

p2 = Plot[Floor[Sin[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi},
   PlotLabel -> Floor[Sin[x]],
   Frame -> True,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed],
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/2], None}},
   ExclusionsStyle -> {Dotted, Red},
   PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-1, 1.1}}];
Show[p2, p1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be there is a better way without using 2 plots, but I could not figure it out.